# How do I create an auth_basic nginx config that excludes any URL path starting with a specific string?

Tags: nginx, basic-authentication

I'm trying to set up nginx basic authentication for the whole website, except for **any URLs starting with "/ghost/"**.

Here's what I have:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name mysite.com;
    root /var/www/ghost/system/nginx-root; # Used for acme.sh SSL verification (https://acme.sh)

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/mysite.com/fullchain.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/mysite.com/mysite.com.key;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;

        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    }

    location /ghost {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;

        auth_basic off;

    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    client_max_body_size 50m;
}
```

(Note: I also tried with `/ghost` - so without using a trailing slash.)

The config above works partially:

- I **can't** access `www.mysite.com` without authenticating ---> GOOD
- I **can** access `www.mysite.com/sub` without authenticating ---> GOOD
- I **can't** access any other path starting with `/sub/` without
  authenticating ---> BAD

How should the config for the `/ghost/`-leading paths looks like?

Comment: It should work. Can you most a more complete configuration that you have?

Comment: @DanilaVershinin I updated my post with the full config.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name mysite.com;
    root /var/www/ghost/system/nginx-root; # Used for acme.sh SSL verification (https://acme.sh)

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/mysite.com/fullchain.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/mysite.com/mysite.com.key;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;

        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    }

    location /ghost/(.*)\ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;

        auth_basic off;

    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    client_max_body_size 50m;
}
```

please the feedback in comment too...

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately. I see the basic auth immediately after accessin `/ghost`.